# Dynamically Copying XML Layout Errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an Android app, and I want to copy some XML code in a Linear Layout, and re-insert it into the Linear Layout so that there are two of the Relative Layouts in the Linear Layout. I would like to do this dynamically by taking this code below:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tileContainerME"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilesAreHERE"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="151dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="2"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="3"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="4"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>            
    </LinearLayout>
```

And then simply turning it into this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tileContainerME"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilesAreHERE"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="151dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="2"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="3"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="4"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>  

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilesAreHERE"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="151dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="2"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="3"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="4"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>                 
    </LinearLayout>
```

See how there would be TWO RelativeLayout sections... I would like to basically make a copy of one and then add it back in (I don't really know how many times I might have to do this in my program, that's why I am not literally inserting it into the XML, I would like to do it from the Java code).
This is what I have so far, but whenever I run it, the layout is wrong. What might be wrong with my code?

```
            LinearLayout m3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tileContainerME);
    RelativeLayout m = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.tilesAreHERE);     
    RelativeLayout m2 = new RelativeLayout(this);

    m2.setLayoutParams(m.getLayoutParams());
    m2.setGravity(m.getGravity());
    m2.setLayoutDirection(m.getLayoutDirection());


    TextView et1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottom1);
    TextView et2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left1);
    TextView et3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right1);
    TextView et4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top1);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(et1.getContext());
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(et2.getContext());
    TextView tv3 = new TextView(et3.getContext());
    TextView tv4 = new TextView(et4.getContext());

    tv1.setLayoutDirection(et1.getLayoutDirection());
    tv2.setLayoutDirection(et2.getLayoutDirection());
    tv3.setLayoutDirection(et3.getLayoutDirection());
    tv4.setLayoutDirection(et4.getLayoutDirection());

    tv1.setGravity(et1.getGravity());
    tv2.setGravity(et2.getGravity());
    tv3.setGravity(et3.getGravity());
    tv4.setGravity(et4.getGravity());

    tv1.setText(et1.getText());
    tv2.setText(et2.getText());
    tv3.setText(et3.getText());
    tv4.setText(et4.getText());

    m2.addView(tv4,et4.getLayoutParams());
    m2.addView(tv3,et3.getLayoutParams());
    m2.addView(tv2,et2.getLayoutParams());
    m2.addView(tv1,et1.getLayoutParams());  

    m3.addView(m2);
```

I don't see what's wrong with my code, any suggestions.....

THIS IS THE FULL XML DATA FILE:

```
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollHORIZON"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tileContainerME"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilesAreHERE"
            android:layout_width="207dp"
            android:layout_height="151dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="1"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/left1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="2"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/right1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/left1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="3"
               />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/top1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="4"
                 />

        </RelativeLayout>           
        </LinearLayout>


    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just wanted to start fresh, restate my question.... I'm still getting errors.....

Comment: But that's not how this site is meant to work. If an answer resolves your current problem then you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. If you don't get an acceptable answer then you should elaborate on the problem in the original question not simply recreate it in a new post

Answer (score 0):

Inflating the same layout inside it once again might help you achieve this.

Try this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    LinearLayout main_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tileContainerME);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null);
    main_layout.addView(child, 1);
}
```

You'll get something like this:

[image]

Comment: LogCat errror:       01-02 11:20:56.804: D/errorBad(1552): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08000a type #0x12 is not valid
I have the Linear Layout in a HorizontalScrollView, so the inflater is having problems.....